# Parser Error while installing an APK,downloaded from my own Server

Tags: java, android, web-services, arrays, auto-update

It may be duplicate question of [stackoverflow.com/questions/11135680/parse-error-while-installing-downloaded-apk-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135680/parse-error-while-installing-downloaded-apk-file), but i didn't find any answers to solve this.

Let me say the issue what i am facing.

I have an application installed in tablet. This application will check for the update whenever it launches. If there is an update it will download the apk and install it automatically. I have used the .NET service as webservice. My .NET service will convert the APK into byte[]array format which is stored in mySQL DB and sent that byte[]Array to my Android Application.

Everything works fine but while installing i am getting

======================================

"PARSER ERROR" Problem parsing a package

======================================

Please don't say check the signature of an apk, everything is okay

Android Code:

```
SoapPrimitive pResponse = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();                           
byte[] bResponse = Base64.decodeBase64((pResponse.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

Struggling alot i have found that the Byte[] response in android is not matching with .net Byte[] as java has signed byte (sbyte -128 to 127)
, while .net has unsigned byte(byte 0 to 255)
eg: In .NET [80,40,2,2,8,0,0,0,12,240,200...........]
    In Android [80,40,2,2,8,0,0,0,12,-16,-56...........]

I can use int unsigned = b & 0xFF; to convert that to unsigned byte[] but my problem is my loop will run for 662600 time.

How can i overcome with this issue, Any suggestions from you guys is much helpful for me.

Comment: I think apk file was not downloaded completely or got corrupted after downloading. Please check the apk size after download the apk file.

Comment: @VivekKumarSrivastava yeah i have checked it. Sizes are same

Comment: I faced the same issue due to different sizes (incomplete downloaded apk). You can also check the minimum OS version defined in your manifest file.

Comment: I had done changes in versionName from android:versionName="1.0" to android:versionName="2.82"

Comment: I am talking about android:minSdkVersion

Comment: Thats what i didnt change any thing other than version number vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had done mistake with installation path where the apk is downloaded.Guys don't bother about the signed and unsigned bytes[]

Steps I had followed for auto updation of an apk from server.

1. Signature of the Previous Version of an apk and  the latest/updated apk should be same.
2. Ensure that the downloaded path and installation path of the apk are same.

NOTE: You can use byte[] or Stream for response from your service